# Using vtkResliceImageViewer or vtkImageViewer2 with Python3+PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, vtk, qvtkwidget

I've written working example for vtkImageViewer:

But any image isn't rendered with vtkImageViewer2 or vtkResliceImageViewer. Have found example based on [PyQt4+Python2.7](https://github.com/MKozuch/DicomVis) but wasn't able to get rendered images also (probably because of wrong versions of libraries).

Are there some examples in Python with these classes?

```
import sys
import vtk
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

from vtk.qt.QVTKRenderWindowInteractor import QVTKRenderWindowInteractor


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)

        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        self.vl = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.vtkWidget = QVTKRenderWindowInteractor(self.frame)
        self.vl.addWidget(self.vtkWidget)

        pathDicomDir = "/path/to/dicom/data"
        reader = vtk.vtkDICOMImageReader()
        reader.SetDirectoryName(pathDicomDir)
        reader.Update()

        self.viewer = vtk.vtkImageViewer()
        # self.viewer = vtk.vtkImageViewer2()
        # self.viewer = vtk.vtkResliceImageViewer()
        self.viewer.SetInputData(reader.GetOutput())

        self.viewer.SetupInteractor(self.vtkWidget)
        self.viewer.SetRenderWindow(self.vtkWidget.GetRenderWindow())
        self.viewer.Render()
        self.frame.setLayout(self.vl)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.frame)

        self.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: https://lorensen.github.io/VTKExamples/site/Python/#pyqt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
self.viewer = vtk.vtkImageViewer2()
```

and add

```
self.vtkWidget.Initialize()
```

**after** self.show()